# Trouble with mounting my usb drive

Tags: boot, usb, mount

This question probably seems like a duplicate, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have a usb flash drive, that I know for a fact is identified by the Pi because I ran `lsusb` and `tail -f /var/log/messages` and both Id'd it. But there was one funny thing, the location was `sda:`

The way I TRIED to mount it was `sudo mkdir /mnt/usb` and `sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/usb` and it succeeded, or at least, it didn't give any errors..

So I tried to cd to it with `cd /media/SAMISCOOLCO` (SAMISCOOLCO is the name if the usb) and it said no file/directory.. so what do I do!?

I need to be able to use the files from command line.. what do I do?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43477/can-not-make-directory-on-my-usb-disk-connected-raspberry-pi-2/43482#43482

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems with your method:

1. You are mounting the drive itself, rather than the partition which holds the data on the drive. You would want to `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb`
2. You are `cd`-ing to a different directory to the one you mounted to. If you've mounted it to `/mnt/usb`, then you need to `cd /mnt/usb`. However, if you've mounted it at `/media/SAMISCOOLCO`, you must `cd /media/SAMISCOOLCO`.

Also, a better method would be to take the USB Drive out, run `ls /dev/sd*` to see all devices beginning with `sd` (might be none), then plug the USB in again, run `ls /dev/sd*` again, and whichever one is new to the list is the one that your drive is. Just make sure you mount `/dev/sdXn`, not `/dev/sdX`. (where `X` is a letter and `n` is a number).

Comment: I see what you are saying, let me go re-do it.